# Basic HTML5 IDE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ide

I've just recently started working with Html5/CSS3/Jquery and am enjoying it quite a bit. To date I've been using visual studio (2010-2012) and asp.net as my primary web development platform.

When working with html5 and jquery though, I would like to have something simpler. Rather than dealing with Microsoft solution files and generic starting templates, I'd like a simple editor with color coding, maybe some auto-complete, and a preview that doesn't require me to launch a web browser repeatedly.

I don't want a WISIWYG of any kind. I started years ago with notepad and have always felt more comfortable working in text than drag and drop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Development IDE Suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140707/web-development-ide-suggestions)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend brackets... it looks awesome, works awesome, and is built in html, css & javascript so you can easily adapt & modify it.

http://brackets.io/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.4.5.html). it has color coding, autocomplete (a downloadable plugin called QuickText) and hotkeys to launch in a web browser. There is no preview but the hotkeys make launching easier

It's free, fast, and small. It works for almost any coding project.
I don't think it's technically an IDE but it's just as powerful as NetBeans or Eclipse and is a fraction of the size

## EDIT:11/21/2013

QuickText is dead if you plan on using a snippets tool FingerText is available

Answer (score 2):

Try [JetBrain's Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). It's a little more expensive than using notepad++ but it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I use [NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/). It has color codinc, auto complet with Ctrl+Space but it doaes not have a preview...

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetBeans or Aptana(under Eclipse or Standalone). Also, IntelliJ IDEA has good support for JS if you want to pay for it(the community edition doesn't have support for JS). I am using NetBeans because I also need Java for the server side and I never wanted other IDE. No preview for these IDEs, but you may find a plugin for it.